# Understanding null hypothesis expression

Tags: binomial-distribution, hypothesis-testing

I have spent time studying about the binomial test, and I have been stuck for a long time. I have a question concerning a null hypotethesis. If, for instance, we have a coin that is being thrown 1000 times, and you have noted there were 400 crown in total. Then, you are making a null hypothesis, which says

$H_0$: the coin is honest.

Let $X$ denote the stochastic variable which represents the number of crownns. My book says, "Under assumption of $H_0$, $X\sim bin(400,1/2)$..."

The question is: What does "under assumption of $H_0$" mean? Here are some possibilities, I thought it would mean

- You assume $H_0$ is true.
- You claim that $H_0$ holds, i.e. you claim the coin is honest, and you never know if it is true or false.

I believe it is the last one. If not, please explain the meaning of the quotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement means that *if* we assume the null hypothesis is true, *then* we can conclude that the distribution of $X$ is the given binomial distribution. Or in other words, the null hypothesis being true *implies* that $X$ has the given distribution.

The rest of the hypothesis test then checks whether this suggests an unlikely event has occurred (i.e. whether the p-value is small), and uses that to determine whether there is evidence we could use to reject the null hypothesis.

Compare it to a standard proof by contradiction:

1. Assume that a statement $P$ is true.
2. Demonstrate that this assumption leads to something impossible.
3. Conclude that therefore $P$ must be false.

This is similar, except that in step 2 we are trying to demonstrate that the assumption leads to something unlikely, so that in step 3 we can't definitively conclude that $P$ is false but it may push us towards it.